# Word for an imagined effect due to an observed event

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Is there a term that is similar to "placebo" but doesn't imply a medication, simply an imagined effect due to an observed phenomenon?

For example, say I hear someone in my office say they got bedbugs over the weekend and they're covered in bites; it might make my skin crawl and make me itch my own skin. Or if I eat a meal and feel fine but someone who eats the same food feels sick and tells me after the meal, then I may feel sick as well since I'm imagining something was wrong with the food when it actually sat perfectly fine in my stomach.

Is there a word for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is (the power of) **[suggestion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suggestion)**:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **2 a** : the process by which a physical or mental state is influenced by a thought or idea · the power of *suggestion*
>
> **b** : the process by which one thought leads to another especially through association of ideas
>
> trying to influence people's thoughts by using *suggestion*
>   The director relies on the power of *suggestion* rather than explicitly showing the murder.